# how to get on the value of specific cells after select datagridview row?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i have datagridview contains more than 100 rows: student name, class and code, i want to get on 3 sequences student codes when select any row to show them in 3 textboxes, whatever the position of the row which i selected.

```
Dim I As Integer = 0
Dim code1 As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(I).Cells(1).Value.ToString
TextBox1.Text = code1

Dim code2 As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(I + 1).Cells(1).Value.ToString
TextBox2.Text = code2

Dim code3 As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(I + 2).Cells(1).Value.ToString
TextBox3.Text = code3
```

i tried to solve it but it's Error

Comment: Are you certain there are 3 selected rows? What is the error and on which line is it occurring?

Comment: in fact i did select one row only, is should to select the 3 rows together?

Comment: Based on your code you'd have to have selected 3 rows. I think you'd actually like to look at the single selected row, and the two subsequent rows. Change your code to get the index of the selected row, and then look at the next rows in the collection.